# Python > Save help() output to formated html file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I have a very long output from help() function and found it a bit hard to find what I am looking for in the script editor. Is it possible to save the help() output as a formatted html file?

Comment: there are other options outside the answers below, you can check this: [python documentation generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125970/python-documentation-generator) for more. I made a quick test with sphinx, but I find it to convoluted to my taste so I cannot get nothing out of it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `pydoc` module to do this in the Python interpreter:

```
import pydoc
pydoc.writedoc("sys")
```

This code will write the documentation for the `sys` module to a file `sys.html` in the current directory. If you want to get documentation for a package, you need to use `pydoc.writedocs()` instead.

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pydoc.html#module-pydoc) say that you can also run `pydoc -w <object>` from the command line, but this didn't work for me without including the full path:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\pydoc.py -w sys
```

Comment: to run pydoc or any other module from anywhere as a script you need to do `python -m <module> [arguments]` in this case that is `python -m pydoc -w sys`

Comment: Thank you so much tjohnson. I had no idea about the pydoc module. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

another option that may be worth mentioning is: redirect the standard output to a file, but this will give you a text file instead of a html

for example

```
import sys
with open("range help.txt","w") as archi:
    t = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = archi
    help(range)
    sys.stdout = t
```

Comment: Wow. That works really well. Thank you so much Copperfield!

Comment: Copperfield, your code worked beautifully. I didn't know how to paste code in this comment section, so I just posted as an answer. Thanks!!

Comment: glad you like it. Also you have the option of edit your question to include new stuff

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help! 
Ok, I put together what I have learned from all of you so far.
This prints everything in my package to a text file. Making it much easier to read and search. I know this is a bit of a hack. So please feel free to improve it. Thanks again!!

```
import sys, os.path, pkgutil, webbrowser
pkgpath ="C:/Users/Haggai/Documents/maya/scripts/mypackage"
my_modules = [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.walk_packages([pkgpath])]
out_file = 'C:/Users/Haggai/Desktop/History.txt'

with open(out_file,"w") as archi:
    t = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = archi
    for i in my_modules:
        help(i)
    sys.stdout = t

webbrowser.open('file://' + out_file)
```

Thank you so much for pointing that out Copperfield, This worked.

```
tmp_list = dir(oSel)
content = '\n'.join(lines)
with open('C:/Users/Haggai/Desktop/dir.txt',"w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(content )
```

Comment: This works great with help() function, but it doesn't work with dir(). Anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: `dir` produce a list of string, it don't print anything so redirecting the stdout don't work on it, you need to process that list in the way you prefer.

Comment: @Copperfield
Thanks I had trouble pasting code here so i just updated the answer above. Thank you so much your help!

Comment: to put code in the comments you need to put it in between ` `` ` , but that look better when is a one line of code like `print "hello"`, also don't use the name of build-in functions as your variable´s name, like `list` when you do that you overwrite the original

Comment: @Copperfield
Got it. just fixed it. Learned so much today :D Thanks again!